# Determine if email address is mailing list address or personal email address

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, data-mining

right now i am building a feature to determine whether email address is mailing list address/group mail address  or personal email address. My current strategy is using manual annotations by human, then those data is used to determine incoming mail address. Example `recruitment@stackoverflow.com`, is mailing address so i store name of this email address `recruitment` and mark as group, so in the future if receive email with name `recruitment`, i ignore it. Do you have any other solution to build this feature without using dataset that build with manual annotations ? any help would be appreciate

Answer (score 0):

It might make sense to use the domain address as a feature, or both names for that matter.  Lots of mailing lists are corporate after all, and lots of personal address come from sites such as Yahoo, Gmail, etc.  Having the additional feature could give you more data on which to create a learning algorithm to categorize mail, such as the Perceptron (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron).  This approach would still involve manual updates, but it would enable your feature to grow smarter over time.